# VSCode launch.json args with space

Tags: visual-studio-code, googletest, vscode-debugger

I am using VSCode to debug my GoogleTest test suite and I have multiple variable arguments. The thing is when I pass an argument with space the arg is not taken in account although it produces no error.

#### What is the correct syntax for arguments with space to be processed ?

---

Here are some informations about the config I use :

**launch.json :**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "TEST",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/out/unit_tests",
            "args": [
                "--gtest_filter=${input:gtest filter}",
                "--gtest_repeat=${input:gtest repeat}",
                "${input:gtest opt}"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/out",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "gtest filter",
            "description": "Input a filter string for Gtest test",
            "default": "*",
            "type": "promptString"
        },
        {
            "id": "gtest repeat",
            "description": "Input a repeat number for Gtest test",
            "default": "1",
            "type": "promptString"
        },
        {
            "id": "gtest opt",
            "description": "Shuffle and/or break",
            "default": "\\\"--gtest_break_on_failure --gtest_shuffle\\\"",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": [
                "\\\"--gtest_shuffle --gtest_break_on_failure\\\"",
                "--gtest_shuffle",
                "--gtest_break_on_failure",
                "",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is `${input:gtest opt}`

**Manual execution :**

```
foo@bar:~$ ./unit_tests --gtest_filter=m --gtest_repeat=1 --gtest_shuffle --gtest_break_on_failure
Note: Google Test filter = m
Note: Randomizing tests' orders with a seed of 94802 .
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test suites.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test suites ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

**Launch from VSCode :**

```
Note: Google Test filter = m
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test suites.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test suites ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

As you can see `"\\\"--gtest_shuffle --gtest_break_on_failure\\\""` is escaped but not processed by GoogleTest. I also tried with simple quotes `"'--gtest_shuffle --gtest_break_on_failure'"` without success.

Comment: Nowadays it's impossible. This feature request is open, but will likely be closed as won't fix https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a string instead of an array in the args. For example:

```
"args": "--gtest_filter=${input:gtest filter} --gtest_repeat=${input:gtest repeat} ${input:gtest opt}",
```